# Is there a way to resurrect yourself with the Glyph of Warding spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

While looking at the *glyph of warding* spell, I noticed that the trigger of the glyph  does not really have boundaries. The spell only states "The most typical" triggers with a few examples.

So I am wondering if you make a *glyph of warding* on the ground with a *revivify* spell stored in it and set the trigger for someone to die in range, is it possible to revive yourself this way?

And for the specific situation I want to use it for. Can you put the glyph under your bed for if you are being assassinated while you sleep?